# Why do I not have an option in VS2013 to publish to a local server?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, publish, vs-web-site-project

I have a web application in VS2013. I click the Publish option and I get the following screen:

[image: Publish initial dialog window]

This doesn't match any of the examples I've seen online where I should have the option to create a new Publish profile and specify a local server. Anyone have any idea how I got this Publish dialog vs. the one in all the docs? And how do I publish to a local server (not my computer, but a Dev server in-house).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click on "Custom" and give the publish profile a name.
2. It will progress to the next screen (pictured below) where you can fill in the details.

[image]

3. The options you can pick from include Web Deploy, Web Deploy Package, FTP, and File System. You probably want either FTP or File System for your Dev server (assuming it's either got an FTP server or is mounted on a network drive.

I think the difference between the documentation and this one is just due to it being a different version / SKU.

Comment: You know, I got there and it just wasn't intuitive that if I entered the name of a new profile I'd get the "local" options since everything seemed to be linked to Azure...

Comment: @RichardSchaefer I think MS want to pretend everyone's going to the cloud. :)